# Execute script on Snort alert

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, snort

I currently am experimenting with a Raspberry Pi. I am running Snort, which is packet detection software. In the case Snort raises an alert, I would want to execute a (Python) script.

Snort is executed, on a raspberry pi as followed:

```
sudo snort -q -A console -i eth0 -c /etc/snort/snort.conf
```

I created a python script that, when called, controls a GPIO pin of a raspberry pi. To bring it more in context; When the raspberry pi receives a ping/ICMP packet, a red alarm light is illuminated and controlled by the same device.

The snort rule currently works, and when an ICMP packet arrives an alert is output to console. I however have no idea how to get snort to execute the python script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are 3 options, hopefully one will work:

- "Strict" `subprocess` approach using subprocess's  `PIPE`s
- Approach using `pexpect` -- "Pexpect is a pure Python module for spawning child applications; controlling them; and responding to expected patterns in their output." -- not that this is the only non-standard package you would have to grab separately from the default python install.
- Approach using pseudoterminals and good-old `select` to read file descriptors

Each of the approaches is bundled in a `try_[SOME APPROACH]` function.  You should be able to update the 3 parameters at  the top, then comment/uncomment one approach at the bottom to give it a shot.

It may be worthwhile testing both halves independently.  In other words snort + my `rpi.py` (below).  Then, if that works, my `timed_printer.py` (below) and your python script to toggle the RPi GPIO.  If they both work independently, then you can be confident not much will need to be done to get the entire workflow operating properly.

**Code**

```
import subprocess

_cmd_lst = ['python', '-u', 'timed_printer.py']  # sudo snort -q -A console -i eth0 -c /etc/snort/snort.conf
_rpi_lst = ['python', '-u', 'rpi.py']            # python script that toggles RPi
_alert = 'TIME'                                  # The keyword you're looking for
                                                 #  in snort output

#===============================================================================

# Simple helper function that calls the RPi toggle script
def toggle_rpi():
    subprocess.call(_rpi_lst)



def try_subprocess(cmd_lst, alert, rpi_lst):
    p = subprocess.Popen(' '.join(cmd_lst), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1)

    try:
        while True:
            for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
                print("try_subprocess() read: %s" % line.strip())

                if alert in line:
                    print("try_subprocess() found alert: %s" % alert)
                    toggle_rpi()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:   print(" Caught Ctrl+C -- killing subprocess...")
    except Exception as ex:     print ex
    finally:
        print("Cleaning up...")
        p.kill()
        print("Goodbye.")



def try_pexpect(cmd_lst, alert, rpi_lst):
    import pexpect # http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html

    p = pexpect.spawn(' '.join(cmd_lst))

    try:
        while True:
            p.expect(alert)     # This blocks until <alert> is found in the output of cmd_str
            print("try_pexpect() found alert: %s" % alert)
            toggle_rpi()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:   print(" Caught Ctrl+C -- killing subprocess...")
    except Exception as ex:     print ex
    finally:
        print("Cleaning up...")
        p.close(force=True)
        print("Goodbye.")



def try_pty(cmd_lst, alert, rpi_lst, MAX_READ=2048):
    import pty, os, select

    mfd, sfd = pty.openpty()

    p = subprocess.Popen(' '.join(cmd_lst), shell=True, stdout=sfd, bufsize=1)

    try:
        while True:
            rlist, _, _, = select.select([mfd], [], [])

            if rlist:
                data = os.read(mfd, MAX_READ)
                print("try_pty() read: %s" % data.strip())
                if not data:
                    print("try_pty() got EOF -- exiting")
                    break
                if alert in data:
                    print("try_pty() found alert: %s" % alert)
                    toggle_rpi()
            elif p.poll() is not None:
                print("try_pty() had subprocess end -- exiting")
                break

    except KeyboardInterrupt:   print(" Caught Ctrl+C -- killing subprocess...")
    except Exception as ex:     print ex
    finally:
        print("Cleaning up...")
        os.close(sfd)
        os.close(mfd)
        p.kill()
        print("Goodbye.")

#===============================================================================

try_subprocess(_cmd_lst, _alert, _rpi_lst)
#try_pexpect(_cmd_lst, _alert, _rpi_lst)
#try_pty(_cmd_lst, _alert, _rpi_lst)
```

**Testing notes**

To emulate your snort script (a script that "hangs", then prints something, then goes back to hanging, etc), I wrote this simple python script that I called `timed_printer.py`:

```
import time
while True:
    print("TIME: %s" % time.time())
    time.sleep(5)
```

And my `rpi.py` file was simply:

```
print("TOGGLING OUTPUT PIN")
```

There's no explicit output flushing here, in an attempt to best emulate normal output.

**Final considerations**

The first approach will read an entire line at a time.  So if you expect your `alert` to be contained within a single line, you'll be fine.

The second approach (`pexpect`) will block until `alert` is encountered.

The third approach will read [*as soon as data is available*](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Waiting-for-I_002fO.html), which I should point out is not necessarily a full line.  If you see `try_pty() read:` with fragments of the snort output lines, causing you to miss alerts, you'll need to add some sort of buffering solution.

**Docs**

- [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)
- [`pexpect`](https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)
- [`pty`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pty.html), [`select`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html)

**References:** [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715847/python-read-streaming-input-from-subprocess-communicate), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12419198/python-subprocess-readlines-hangs/12471855#12471855)

Comment: I don't see how this answers the original question: *"run python script on snort alert"*. Your answer tries to show how to read output from a subprocess that behaves diffferently if it is not run in a terminal. There are multiple issues in the code e.g., it looks like `try_pty()` may hang foreever (there is no timeout on `select` and both `mfd` may not see EOF until `sfd` is closed). Notice: that the timeout is present in [the referenced answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12471855/4279). I should probably update it, to add a simpler code, with less subtle details.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian -- all three examples worked without issue for me -- if you have test cases that fail, please let me know and I'll modify the code accordingly.

Comment: I was *wrong*: your code indeed tries to run a python script (`rpi.py`) on snort alert (simulated by `'timed_printer.py'` here). Moreover it does not  matter that `try_pty()` may hang at the end because you do not expect `snort` to exit by itself without Ctrl+C. Your code still have other issues: `subprocess` solution won't detect alerts "in real-time" if `snort` doesn't flush its stdout buffer on each alert; `pty`, `pexpect` solution workaround it. `' '.join(cmd_lst)` may break (space, shell meta-character); you can pass `cmd_lst` here. No need to use `shell=True`. `while True` is unnecessary

Comment: `alert in line` won't work on Python 3. What happens if the time between alerts exceeds the default `pexpect` timeout?

Comment: here's a simplified version of your `pty` case: [`run-script-on-alert-pty.py`](https://gist.github.com/zed/6c8dde3216c005232934#file-run-script-on-alert-pty-py)

Answer (score 1):

You could instead log the alerts to a file and then implement something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28676484/how-can-i-generate-immediate-pop-up-when-a-traffic-matched-with-a-snort-rule/28733411#28733411), but you would just do a call to your python script instead of notify-send.

Experimental things in snort can be hard to figure out because there isn't a lot of support out there for them when something goes wrong.

Comment: problem with this implementation is that snort [options] > file.txt    appears to be buffering the output. When this command is terminated it will write its buffer to the file. So you can only read the changes in this file after terminating the process. When using snort [options] | [process 2], you pipe the stdout to the stdin of process 2. The problem with this implementation is that snort does not use EOL or EOF and therefore, the pipe waits for the end of the line before it can process it elsewhere

Comment: You're saying that the file.txt file, where snort is logging alerts to, only writes to the file when the snort process dies? can you run snort in daemon mode (-D)?

Answer (score 0):

If piping the output delays receiving alerts until snort's stdout buffer is flushed:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

snort_process = Popen(['snort', '-A', 'console', '-c', 'snort.conf'],
                      stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, bufsize=1,
                      universal_newlines=True, close_fds=True)
with snort_process.stdout:
    for line in iter(snort_process.stdout.readline, ''):
        #XXX run python script here:
        #    subprocess.call([sys.executable or 'python', '-m', 'your_module'])
        print(line, end='')
rc = snort_process.wait()
```

Then you could [try a pseudo-tty to enable line-buffereing on snort's side](https://gist.github.com/zed/6c8dde3216c005232934#file-run-script-on-alert-pty-py).

Or run `snort -A unsock` command and print each alert as soon as it is generated using Unix domain sockets:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import ctypes
import os
import socket
from subprocess import Popen
from snort import Alertpkt

# listen for alerts using unix domain sockets (UDS)
snort_log_dir = os.getcwd()
server_address = os.path.join(snort_log_dir, 'snort_alert')
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
try:
    os.remove(server_address)
except OSError:
    pass
sock.bind(server_address)

# start snort process
snort_process = Popen(['snort', '-A', 'unsock', '-l', snort_log_dir,
                       '-c', 'snort.conf'], close_fds=True)
# receive alerts
alert = Alertpkt()
try:
    while 1:
        if sock.recv_into(alert) != ctypes.sizeof(alert):
            break # EOF
        #XXX run python script here `subprocess.call([sys.executable or 'python', '-m', 'your_module'])`
        print("{:03d} {}".format(alert.val, alert.data))
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    sock.close()
    os.remove(server_address)
    if snort_process.poll() is None: # the process is still running
        snort_process.kill()
        snort_process.wait() # wait for snort process to exit
```

In your case you could run a script on each alert instead of printing.

[`snort.Alertpkt` is a ctypes's defition of C `struct Alertpkt`](https://gist.github.com/zed/6c8dde3216c005232934#file-snort-py).

To try it, you could download [the gist that contains a dummy `snort` script in addition to all the python modules](https://gist.github.com/zed/6c8dde3216c005232934#file-snort) and run  `run-script-on-alert-unsock.py` (or `run-script-on-alert-pty.py`).